# C# struct using "new" still on stack or heap?

Tags: c#, struct, stack, store, heap-memory

It's said that class objects are allocated on heap using new, and struct object can declare directly on stack. But if I use "new" to allocate a struct, where is it stored? Like this:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public int mI;
    public string mS;
}

MyStruct s1;
s1.mI = 1;
s1.mS = "ab";

MyStruct s2 = new MyStruct
{
    mI = 2,
    mS = "xy"
};
```

I know "s1" is on heap, what about "s2"?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: *stack/heap* is an *implementation detail*, is there an reason this concerns you?

Comment: Have you read this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/

Comment: @Thangadurai not necessarily always

Comment: Usually there´s no reason to think about where an object is stored, this could even be on a disc or any arbitrary storage and should not affect the **semnatics** of your object - which is **value-types** and **reference-types**. Those are the terms you should care for.